# How do you catch canLaunch exceptions using url_launcher in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Using the code from the package I was unable to catch the exception. Note that I would like to catch this specific exception.

```
// from https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher
_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'myscheme://myurl';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}

// my code
try {
  _launchURL();
}
catch (e)
{
  // although the exception occurs, this never happens, and I would rather catch the exact canLaunch exception
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to put the try catch statement inside the function. I believe what is happening is that the try/catch statement is only applying for the function call and although it is async I dont believe that it actually tries and returns exeptions.

So the solution would look somethink like this:

```
_launchURL() async {
  try{

  const url = 'myscheme://myurl';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
  }

  catch(e){
  //debug e
  }
}

// my code
launchURL();
```

Comment: Yes I can see how that would work. Is that the intended way to handle canLaunch exceptions?

Comment: I am not sure as I am not familliar wih the url_launcher package. But if you catch the exceptions I dont see a reason why it wouldnt give you one for the canLaunch.

Comment: I would also take a look at the url that you are trying to load. If its the same one that is in the question I think that is  the problem why it gives you an error. Try setting it to https://www.google.com or something simillar.

Comment: My intention is to catch exceptions when myscheme:// is unable to launch. So the purpose is to use url_launcher with a non-standard url scheme.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.then()` for business logic.

For me, it is used to ***check if the app can be opened*** on the device.

Can be solution below,

```
-->  url_launcher: ^6.0.2
-->  https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

launch(appLink).then(
  (bool isLaunch) {
    print('isLaunch: $isLaunch');
    if (isLaunch) {
      // Launch Success
    } else {
      // Launch Fail
    }
  },
  onError: (e) {
    print('onError: $e');
  },
).catchError(
  (ex) => print('catchError: $ex'),
);
```

Work for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
Future<void> _launch(String url) async {
await canLaunch(url)
    ? await launch(url)
    : throw 'Could not launch $url';
```

}